# Tag synonym request: [css2] -> [css]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

These days, CSS usually refers to CSS2+. So, I suggest to map [css2](/questions/tagged/css2) to [css](/questions/tagged/css).

I tried it myself...:

[image: Suggest a css synonym: css2 Suggest Failed to propose synonym: Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators (click on this box to dismiss)]

Comment: But then how can you use [css2] to indicate that you are not asking about css3?

Comment: I actually think this is a good idea. `css2` doesn't mean anything useful on Stack Overflow. It's usually (ab)used to mean "I need this to work in older browsers such as IE7". However, IE7 supports even some CSS3, for example `~` and `overflow-y`. There are currently 61 questions tagged `css2`, and I think it could be removed from every question. Only [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437835/parsing-css-2-1-with-the-correct-css-parsing-conventions-in-antlr) arguably needs it, but the question still makes perfect sense without it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good idea.  We have the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag to talk about the general field of .NET, as well as version-specific tags (such as [.net-4.5](/questions/tagged/.net-4.5)) for items that are specific (or more likely, introduced) in *that* specific version.

The [css](/questions/tagged/css) tags are no different.  There are times when you are speaking about CSS in general (or, the version that is most prevalent/widely-adopted at the time), but there are times when you want to speak about a *specific* version; this situation is when something isn't fully baked/just released so you can differentiate the technologies when an influx of new questions are going to come in on that new technology.

Going back and removing the version-specific tags (you're suggesting that [css](/questions/tagged/css) is version one and that it be merged into version two) generally isn't a good idea.  If anything, there might be people still using the old technology (depending on what we're talking about), and still need to differentiate between the two.

Comment: this makes sense